# impose condition on random matrix such that its element sum and row sum satisfies certain condition

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-matrices

Assume $a_{ij}:=1+ c_{ij}$ is element of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices $A$ with diagonal element equals to $0$.

What condition we can impose on matrix $C$ (whose elements are $c_{ij}$), such that

$$pn^2+qn+r\leq \sqrt{2}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_{ij}+\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}a_{ij}$$